# Visual Studio 2015 crashes on Schema Compare

Tags: sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2015, schema-compare

Every time I try to do a Schema Compare against my local database in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio crashes and restarts itself.

I've already tried restarting my PC and deleting and recreating the database (by restoring it).

I am running Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise on a Windows 7 Ultimate x64 machine with SQL Server 2012 installed.

Comment: I have Windows 10 x64 and it reproduces as well.

Comment: I'm going to tentatively suggest this is fixed in Update 3 Version 14.0.25424. I experienced the same behavior (with Sql Server 2014) before the upgrade, and after the upgrade was able to perform at least one Compare without crashing. Note. This is the second "Update 3" released by Microsoft. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt752379.aspx

Comment: try Visual Studio 2015 open with administrator privileges.